# Does tizen and orsay cache static files on Smart TVs?

Tags: caching, toast, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

I'm developing TV app with [TOAST](http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/extension-libraries/toast/) and in one of my menu I have a catalog with about 100 images.

If I load images like below does tizen and orsey cache them and use them later or they read those from server every time.

```
<div style="background-image:url(http://Mydomain/pages/4.jpg)"></div>
```

I can think about some other solutions like:

- Add those images to TV app package (But in that case, the package size would be about 20MB)
- Get them with ajax and store them locally and than use them
  What is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on Smarttv platforms long time. Sadly It seems best way is serve static files with app package.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Yes you are right but i am new at platform. So it says you have to have 50 reputation to comment

Comment: I know but there is reason why you are not allowed to comment when below 50 reputation. Please only post answers that actually answer the question.